# Changing group by statement to get field not being grouped

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following data:

```
id   date_modified   value
1    some_date       4
1    some_date       3
1    some_date       1
2    some_date       5
3    some_date       8
3    some_date       7
...
```

and this query gets the `id` and `date_modified` where `date_modified` is the latest date:

```
select bh.id, max(bh.date_modified) 
from my_table bh
group by bh.id;
```

which does this:

```
id   date_modified  
1    some_date       
2    some_date       
3    some_date       
...
```

where each date is the latest date for each `id` which is nearly what I want.

How do I change the `group by` to get the `value` out?  It's the `value` that I'm interested in but I need to group using the `id`.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need the `MAX(value)` or the value for the `MAX(date_modified)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, date_modified, value
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id, date_modified, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITIOn BY Id ORDER BY date_modified DESC) RN
    FROM tbl
) A
WHERE RN = 1
```